# How is {1..100} called in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, brace-expansion

I am aware that `{1..100}` creates the sequence of numbers 1 to 100. I would like to know how this two dots syntax is called? Is it a shortcut for "seq"? Something else? Could you please provide link to docs?

```
for i in {1..100}
do
 echo $i
done
```

Answer (score 6):

The `{x..y}` syntax (particular case of the `{x..y..incr}` syntax) is called *sequence expression* in Bash docs, and its evaluation is triggered by the so-called *brace expansion* mechanism.

Albeit the `seq` command achieves a similar goal (see example session below), it is very different from writing `{x..y..incr}`, which is builtin in Bash and thereby does not spin a process (unlike the `seq` command which is a binary from coreutils).

Another difference is that `seq` supports variables (e.g., `seq "$x" "$y"` will work out-of-the-box), while the string `{$x..$y}` won't be expanded.

Relevant docs can be found at [this page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#index-brace-expansion).

```
$ echo {1..3}
1 2 3
$ echo {1..6..2}
1 3 5
$ seq 1 3
1
2
3
$ seq 1 2 6
1
3
5
$ type seq
seq is hashed (/usr/bin/seq)
```

Comment: Maybe it is worth to point out, that OTOH `seq` can be used to create a sequence, where start and/or end are variables. This is not possible with a sequence expression.

Comment: Just for completeness (since the OP also attached for whatever reason the _zsh_  tag to his question): According to the Zsh docs, the term _sequence expression_ does not see to be used. Instead, this is in zsh simply a special case of _brace expansion_. Maybe the Zsh-folks did not think it necessaray to give a special name for this feature.